# Is there a database for tslint rules?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I was looking around the available ts-lint rules and I got really confused with all of them, because the documentation is either static web pages, that might not be up to date, or static readme files that list some of their details.

And I was wondering, is there a database for all the tslint rules, that names them and especially lists where they come from? Because with a full tslint.json configuration file, it is hard to know where to look for a description and/or the options for some of the rules.

Comment: Judging by the [source](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/tree/master/docs), those pages are dynamically generated based on the rules defined in the current version. All the documentation you would want is on those pages already.

Comment: @jhpratt actually wanted to add the tslint-rules tag, but not enough reputation for that, because that would both specify tslint and rules more.

Comment: Yeah, that tag doesn't exist, likely because any question tagged taking would also be tagged with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that there was no database / common list available, I used this as a programming exercise to build one myself. It is not 100% polished and might also be missing a rule package here and there, but it is a start. Feedback welcome.

https://trex.totkeks.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

Sort of!

The TSLint rules that come with the TSLint package itself are all documented on https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules. That is auto-generated from [what's on GitHub](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/). and kept up-to-date with the latest release. If you're just using the `tslint` package without any community rulesets, that's all you need.

Community rulesets vary in documentation practices, but generally each has some form of documentation. For example:

- [codelyzer](http://codelyzer.com/rules/) also has a snazzy webpage
- [tslint-eslint-rules](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules) documents rules in its README.md
- [tslint-microsoft-contrib](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) documents rules in its README.md
- [tslint-react](https://github.com/palantir/tslint-react) documents rules in its README.md

Unfortunately, there isn't one database for all the community rulesets *(those are just some of the more popular ones)*. There are some rules that are duplicated or duplicated-but-slightly-different across the various packages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also found those, but had the same issue you mentioned. It is hard to get an overview, when you don't know exactly where to look. Of course I can cross check all those READMEs and webpages, but it would be so much easier if there would be one page listing them all. Would also make it easier to find similar rules (e.g. by name or description).
Guess I will try to come up with something on my own.